# betrügen vs täuschen

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonym

According to Duden, "betrügen" may mean:

> 1. to deceive
> 2. to cheat (through scam/fraud cause something) . (Duden uses "um"
>    in most examples, eg " jemanden um 1000 Euro betrügen")
> 3. to cheat on (without the knowledge of your
>    wife/husband/boyfriend/girlfriend, have sex with other people) ( =
>    fremdgehen)

Also according to Duden, "täuschen" may mean:

> 1. to deceive
> 2. to be mistaken (sich täuschen)

Are there any differences in meaning (1) of both verbs? Is *betrügen/täuschen* interchangeable in these examples?

> 1. einen Freund, einen Kunden, einen Geschäftspartner, eine Firma betrügen/täuschen
> 2. Ich sehe mich in meinen Erwartungen betrogen/getäuscht
> 3. Seine Versprechen haben mich betrogen/getäuscht
> 4. Mein Gedächtnis hat mich betrogen/getäuscht

Also, I suspect that "sich betrügen" is a synonym of "sich täuschen", so I add a last example:

> 5. Ich habe mich betrogen/getäuscht, als ich dachte, ich könnte Präsident sein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, I suspect that "sich betrügen" is a synonym of "sich täuschen"

No. "Sich täuschen" means that you by yourself consider information or assumptions as correct which actually are wrong.
"Sich betrügen" is actually not possible. "Betrügen" is always something that only somebody else does to you.
However, the word "Selbstbetrug" (-> "sich selbst betrügen") exists, what means that you are not willing to admit you are wrong with something, although you actually know it.

Anyway, your example (3) is only correct with "getäuscht":

> Seine Versprechen haben mich getäuscht.

"Seine Versprechen" aren't a person, so they can't "betrügen". However:

> Er hat mich getäuscht/betrogen.

In this case both verbs are feasible, if it's not in the context of your example

> (3) to cheat on (without the knowledge of your
>   wife/husband/boyfriend/girlfriend, have sex with other people) ( =
>   fremdgehen)

Here only "betrügen" can be used:

"Ich dachte, er ist mir treu!" <- wrong assumption... 
"Da habe ich mich getäuscht!" <- ... led to "sich täuschen"
"Er hat mich betrogen!" <- "Er ist fremdgegangen." Nobody would ever say "Er hat mich getäuscht."

Apart from the exceptions above, "betrügen" can theoretically be used as a synonym to "täuschen". However, "betrügen" is way more common, especially when it's about money.

Comment: Regarding the reflexive use of betrügen, one of the examples given by Duden in the definition of "betrügen" is "sich selbst betrügen". I suppose that is different from "sich betrügen"?

Comment: It's the same, although *selbst* is added so frequently that omitting it may feel wrong. It means *lying to yourself*, which apparently can be useful: [link](http://magazin.spiegel.de/EpubDelivery/spiegel/pdf/96239004) (note the absence of *selbst*)

Answer (score 2):

Both words may mean *deception*, but a *Täuschung* is much milder than *Betrug*.

One might say: "Du hast mich vorhin getäuscht! Du hast gesagt, das Restaurant ist nur noch 500 Meter entfernt und jetzt laufen wir bereits zwei Stunden." You would never use "betrogen". However, when you believe that your partner cheated on you, you would say "Du hast mich mit X. betrogen!".

Formally, *Betrug* is an act of fraud, a *Täuschung* is a deception. *Betrug* and *Täuschung* are both found in criminal law:

> § 263 StGB Betrug
>
> (1) Wer in der Absicht, sich oder einem Dritten einen rechtswidrigen Vermögensvorteil zu verschaffen, das Vermögen eines anderen dadurch beschädigt, daß er durch Vorspiegelung falscher oder durch Entstellung oder Unterdrückung wahrer Tatsachen einen Irrtum erregt oder unterhält, wird mit Freiheitsstrafe **bis zu fünf Jahren** oder mit Geldstrafe bestraft.
>
> (2) [..]

and

> § 108 StGB Täuschung
>
> (1) Wer einem anderen in seinen Rechten dadurch absichtlich einen Schaden zufügt, daß er ihn oder einen Dritten durch Täuschung über Tatsachen zu einer Handlung, Duldung oder Unterlassung verleitet, die den Schaden herbeiführt, ist mit Freiheitsstrafe **bis zu einem Jahr** oder mit Geldstrafe bis zu 720 Tagessätzen zu bestrafen.
>
> (2) [..]

In the case of *Täuschung*, intentionality is an additional requirement to constitute a criminal offense. A *Täuschung* based on a simple misunderstanding is no offense. *Betrug* is necessarily intentional.

Comment: In the law definition, "betrügen" must cause a financial damage. Although "betrügen" is most common used word in this context, I think that, in general, it is not restricted to it (eg "sich selbst betrügen"). Therefore, it is not clear to me why "betrügen" is *impossible* in your restaurant example. What is the criteria that distinguishes both words? Just saying that one is stronger than another seems a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: @Alan Evangelista: Yes, a "Betrug" in the legal sense requires a harm to someone else's property. The reason why "Betrug" wouldn't work in the restaurant case is that it is too strong a word. You wouldn't use it for chiding someone - only if you're willing to risk serious consequences (like a definitive rupture of a relationship or a bare-knuckle fight).